# How to apply alternating background color to divs which are not siblings

Tags: html, css

I'd like **aaaa** and **bbbb** to have red background. How can I do this , the usual answers dont seem to work since the target divs are not siblings

Here is my CSS/HTML:

```css
div.rules-container>div.ng-star-inserted>div.rules-form:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="rules-container">
  <div class="ng-star-inserted">
    <div class="rules-form">
      aaaaaaaaaaaa
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ng-star-inserted">
    <div class="rules-form">
      bbbbbbbbbb
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ng-star-inserted">
    <div class="rules-form">
      ccccccccccccc
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `:nth-child(odd)`.

**Answer 1:**

If you want all the odd numbers, then do this:

```css
.rules-container .ng-star-inserted:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: red;
  }
```

```html
<div class="rules-container">
  <div class="ng-star-inserted">
    <div class="rules-form">
      aaaaaaaaaaaa
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ng-star-inserted">
    <div class="rules-form">
      bbbbbbbbbb
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ng-star-inserted">
    <div class="rules-form">
      ccccccccccccc
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="ng-star-inserted">
    <div class="rules-form">
      dddddddddddddd
    </div>
  </div>
  
  
  <div class="ng-star-inserted">
    <div class="rules-form">
      eeeeeeeeeeeeee
    </div>
  </div>
```

**Answer 2:**

If you only want 1 & 3, not 5 , then change the css to:

```css
.rules-container .ng-star-inserted:nth-child(1), .rules-container .ng-star-inserted:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="rules-container">
  <div class="ng-star-inserted">
    <div class="rules-form">
      aaaaaaaaaaaa
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ng-star-inserted">
    <div class="rules-form">
      bbbbbbbbbb
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ng-star-inserted">
    <div class="rules-form">
      ccccccccccccc
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="ng-star-inserted">
    <div class="rules-form">
      dddddddddddddd
    </div>
  </div>
  
  
  <div class="ng-star-inserted">
    <div class="rules-form">
      eeeeeeeeeeeeee
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you, but this will apply to all children under .ng-star-inserted across the page. I want to restrict to only children of rules-container, i'd like that to be part of the selector.

Comment: @SajjanSarkar That is very easy, just add the `.rules-container` infront the ng-star. I've edited the answer and also added *dddddd* & *eeeeee* which will be outside rules-container so that you can see it does not get affected :)

Comment: So what this updated answer does is, it finds the ng-star class which has to be within a rules-container class. Thus, this way, it does not affect ng-star classes which are not within rules-container.